# ASP.net core field of viewmodel is required despite the fact that it is nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I am building an web-app with Asp.net core. I am using the build-in core validation methodology. I have a form where I would like to apply client-side validation using data annotations. My model looks like the following:

```
[Display(Name= "Address")] 
[Required]
[StringLength(80, MinimumLength = 5)]
public string Address { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "When it is needed")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime TakeDownDate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Exact time")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan ExactTimeToTakeDown { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Content of container")]
public ContainerContentEnum? Content { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "When to take up")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? TakeUpDate { get; set; }   

[Display(Name= "Other comment")]
[StringLength(250)]
public string Other { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Multiple round")]
public bool MaybeMoreRound { get; set; }
```

Let's see the TakeUpDate property. It is nullable, so I allow it for the user to not type anything in the field to submit the form. After the form is submitted, it is processed by the corresponding controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult SaveNewClaim(NewClaimViewModel newClaim)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _claimsRepository.Insert(_newClaimViewModelToClaimConverterService.Convert(newClaim));
        return CreateJsonResult(true, "Az igény sikeresen lementésre került");
    }

    return CreateJsonResult(false, GetErrorMessages());
}

private JsonResult CreateJsonResult(bool isSuccess, string responseMessage)
{
    return Json(new
        {
            success = isSuccess,
            responseText = responseMessage
        }
    );
}

private string GetErrorMessages()
{
    return string.Join(";\n", ModelState.Values
        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
}
```

And as for the view, the .cshtml file looks like the following:

```
@using App.ViewModels.ClaimViewModels.ClaimModels
@model App.ViewModels.ClaimViewModels.ClaimModels.NewClaimViewModel

<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                <h3><b>Új igény felvétele</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <form asp-action="SaveNewClaim" id="EventForm" class="well">
                    <input type="hidden" id="eventID" class="form-control">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Address" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="TakeDownDate" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input asp-for="TakeDownDate" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="TakeDownDate" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ExactTimeToTakeDown" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input asp-for="ExactTimeToTakeDown" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ExactTimeToTakeDown" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Content" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <select asp-for="Content" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<MokaKukaMap.Domain.Model.ContainerContentEnum>()" class="form-control">
                                <option selected="selected" value="">Kérem válassz</option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="TakeUpDate" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input asp-for="TakeUpDate" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="TakeUpDate" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Other" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input asp-for="Other" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Other" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="MaybeMoreRound" class=""></label>
                        <div class="">
                            <input asp-for="MaybeMoreRound" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="MaybeMoreRound" class="text-danger"> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnPopupCancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Vissza</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnPopupSave" class="btn btn-primary">Igény mentése</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Last but not least my ajax post (click event) on submit button:

```
$('#btnPopupSave').click(function () {
    var dataRow = {
        Address: $('#Address').val(),
        TakeDownDate: $('#TakeDownDate').val(),
        ExactTimeToTakeDown: $('#ExactTimeToTakeDown').val(),
        Content: $('#Content').val(),
        TakeUpDate: $('#TakeUpDate').val(),
        Other: $('#Other').val(),
        MaybeMoreRound: $('#MaybeMoreRound').val()
    }

    console.log('Submitting form...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'SaveNewClaim',
        data: dataRow,
        headers:
        {
            "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $('#calendarModal').modal('hide');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
            else {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function(xMlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Despite the fact that I set the TakeUpDate nullable, my model is still invalid and I got the following error message:
The value 'When to take up' is invalid.
[image]

To be honest I checked every relating Q/As here in stackoverflow, and also other forums, and all of them say that it is the right way to set a field nullable.

If you need any more code, I add it to this question right away...

Comment: What type is being passed to the controller for the TakeUpDate? If you just have a blank textbox on your form then the controller will be receiving an empty string; not a nullable DateTime.

Comment: The error message `The value 'When to take up' is invalid` tells me that it's trying to parse 'When to take up' as a string. Can you post your markup (razor)

Comment: @melkisadek The passed type is: "System.Date.DateTime?" and its value is null.

Comment: @Alex I updated my question

Comment: You need to debug back up the call chain. If the controller is receiving the correct type then the model should validate. I would recommend testing it explicitly by adding a new nullable DateTime variable with the date set as Now() then assigning that to `newClaim.TakeUpDate` just before the call to `ModelState.IsValid`. If that works, try it with `null`.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript AJAX-post code which submits the request.

Comment: @PradeepKumar I added to it, thanks for your help

Comment: @melkisadek I have done it with both DateTime.Now and null, but my model is still invalid. Very misty -.-'

Comment: When you debug, the Value of which Key is showing an error on the debug properties of the ModelState? What error is it showing?

Comment: @melkisadek i added a picture for that ;)

Comment: Thanks. If you drill down into the TakeUpDate SubKey you should be able to find the Attempted Value under it's Value. What is that showing?

Comment: @melkisadek the attempted value is an empty string ("")...mhh. And the error is: "The When to take up field is required."

Comment: So your form is passing an empty string not a nullable DateTime type. You need to capture that before the ModelState.IsValid call and change it to a null. The suggestion from 2 days ago should have worked. In the SaveNewClaim action of the controller, above the line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` write `newClaim.TakeUpDate = null;`. Then check the debug properties Attempted Value again.

Comment: @melkisadek I have set it to null before the if statement, and it is still an empty string.

Comment: @melkisadek the fact is that the attempted value for the TakeDownDate is also a string, bot not empty ofc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to be checking. If explicitly setting a null value still shows an empty string then there is something wrong elsewhere that your code isn't showing. If you debug just after the null assignment, what does newClaim.TakeUpDate show as Type and Value?

Comment: ehh, really interesting issue :) I checked it, the type is "System.Date.Time?" and the value is "null". I am wondering of what would happen if I would use Razor markup in the view instead of html. What is your opinion? Which one is the moderner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you're passing an empty string back to the controller.

You either need to capture that empty string and convert it to a null before model binding takes place, or you need to work around the known 'bug' and deal with the fact your validation will always fail at this point.

You might be able to change the Ajax POST to explicitly send a null.

Alternatively (and probably what I'd do) is just sanity check your date in the controller. If it's an empty string, then remove it from the ModelState so it isn't flagged as invalid (as you already know what it is and why). The ModelState will still validate the other fields as normal.

Something like the following:

```
public IActionResult SaveNewClaim(NewClaimViewModel newClaim)
{
    if (newClaim.TakeUpDate == "")
    {
        ModelState.Remove("TakeUpDate");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        newClaim.TakeUpDate = null;

        _claimsRepository.Insert(_newClaimViewModelToClaimConverterService.Convert(newClaim));
        return CreateJsonResult(true, "Az igény sikeresen lementésre került");
    }

    return CreateJsonResult(false, GetErrorMessages());
}
```