# Invalid ModelState on nullable int property with 'Id' in its name .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I do PUT/POST queries with getting data from form. I mean:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] Model model) { ... }
```

And in this `Model` I have property `int? FromId`.

When I'm trying to validate `ModelState` I'm getting the following error:

> "The value 'null' is not valid for FromId."

I don't have any attributes on this property.

If I change my property `FromId` to `From` then it works fine.

What's the reason of it? And how can I resolve it?

Comment: I can't answer your question other than to say that names in MVC are important and its not always obvious when the system uses certain text in its own operation

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764995/asp-net-core-field-of-viewmodel-is-required-despite-the-fact-that-it-is-nullable

Comment: Are you sending literally `null` as the value in your request? That's the only way I can reproduce your error, but of course the string `"null"` isn't convertible to `int?`.

Comment: Yes, `FromId = null` when I debug code. Not a string. If I put `FromId = 0` it works fine.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/2WAildR93xwT

Comment: Your screenshot confirms my earlier comment. You're passing the *string* `null` which cannot be converted into `int?`. In other words, the problem here is your *client*, which is sending bad data.

Comment: Okay, then why I don't see the same error for boolean properties? For example `enabledForDocument`

Comment: All the values that get passed through are strings. The strings `"true"` and `"false"` get converted into their corresponding `bool` values. When you have an `int`, it's actually a string e.g. `"1"` which gets converted into a number or fails if it's *not* convertible to `int`. The string `"null"` does not have any special meaning - you need to exclude your `FromId` from the request (or leave it empty as in your screenshot for e.g. `bcc`).